# Why is my footer not going to the bottom?

Tags: html, css, position, footer

The footer that I have keeps sticking to my div in the center and I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

I think it is something regarding the position but I don't know what. I tried changing the position of the background div because I thought with it being absolute it was getting ignored and therefore the footer was coming up, however, that does not seem to be the case.

Here is my code snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  padding-top: 44px;
}

nav a {
  margin: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 33px;
}

nav a:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#contact-background {
  width: 100%;
}

.contact {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 60%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 10%);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px #2c2418;
}

.info {
  text-align: center;
}

.question {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Adamas;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 40px;
  word-spacing: -40px;
}

h1 {
  top: -40px;
}

.divide {
  display: flex;
}

.logo,
.form {
  flex: 1;
  width: 50%;
}

#contact-logo {
  width: 100%;
}

input,
textarea {
  width: 90%;
  color: white;
}

.ui-autocomplete {
  background-color: #eceff1;
  width: 100px;
}

.form {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

form {
  width: 100%;
}

.submit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 120%);
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder,
#submit-button {
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  color: white;
}

input,
textarea,
#submit-button {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border: 0;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-link {
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.footer-link:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Contact Us</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact-us.css" />
  <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/11e961d83e08fc7c0815dd269ff231da?family=Adamas" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="contact-us.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="background">
    <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/3959339.jpg" id="contact-background">
  </div>

  <div class="nav">
    <nav>
      <a id="nav1" href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a id="nav2" href="services.html">Services</a>
      <a id="nav3" href="founder2.html">Founder</a>
      <a id="nav4" href="about-us.html">About Us</a>
      <a id="nav5" href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a>
    </nav>
  </div>


  <div class="contact">
    <div class="info">
      <h1 class="question">CONTACT US</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="divide">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="contact-logo.png" id="contact-logo">
      </div>

      <div class="form">
        <form action="#">
          <label for="fname"></label>
          <p><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Name" size="60"></p>
          <label for="email"></label>
          <p><input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="What's your email?" size="60"></p>
          <label for="phone"></label>
          <p><input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="What's your phone number?" size="60"></p>
          <label for="tags"> </label>
          <p><input id="tags" placeholder="What question do you have?"></p>
          <label for="info"></label>
          <p><textarea id="info" name="info" placeholder="More information..." rows="7 " cols="49"></textarea></p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="submit">
      <button id="submit-button">Send Message</button>
    </div>
  </div>


  <footer>
    <p>&copy; Random Analytix. All rights reserved. </p>
    <a class="footer-link" href="https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/">CSS Validator</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="https://validator.w3.org">HTML Validator</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="services.html">Services</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="founder2.html">Founder</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="about-us.html">Our Story</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a>
  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

[image: Page shot]

Comment: Isn't the footer working fine in the snippet?

Comment: Here, I will upload a screenshot of what is happening to show you. I couldn't find a way to add images that were making up the background.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using absolute to position the footer at the bottom. Delete that line and it works fine.

Comment: It just disappears.

Comment: I edited the code snippet if you want to run it and open it in full page view to see.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;


}

nav {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    padding-top: 44px;
}


nav a {
    margin: 80px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 33px;
}

nav a:hover {
    opacity: .5;
}

.background {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

#contact-background {
    width: 100%;

}

.contact {
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 60%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 10%);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px #2c2418;

}

.info {
    text-align: center;

}

.question {
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Adamas;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 40px;
    word-spacing: -40px;
}

h1 {
    top: -40px;
}

.divide {
    display: flex;
}

.logo, .form {
    flex: 1;
    width: 50%;
}

#contact-logo {
    width: 100%;
}


input, textarea {
    width: 90%;
    color: white;
}


.ui-autocomplete {
    background-color: #eceff1;
    width: 100px;
}


.form {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

form {
    width: 100%;
}


.submit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 120%);

}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder, textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder, #submit-button {
   font-family: "Times New Roman";
    color: white;
}

input, textarea, #submit-button{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    border: 0;
}


footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: gray;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer-link {
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.footer-link:hover {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contact Us</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact-us.css" />
    <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/11e961d83e08fc7c0815dd269ff231da?family=Adamas" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="contact-us.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="background">
    <img src="neural.jpeg" id="contact-background">
</div>

<div class="nav">
    <nav>
        <a id="nav1" href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a id="nav2" href="services.html">Services</a>
        <a id="nav3" href="founder2.html">Founder</a>
        <a id="nav4" href="about-us.html">About Us</a>
        <a id="nav5" href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a>
    </nav>
</div>


<div class="contact">
    <div class="info">
        <h1 class="question">CONTACT US</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="divide">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="contact-logo.png" id="contact-logo">
        </div>

        <div class="form">
            <form action="#">
                <label for="fname"></label>
                <p><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Name" size="60"></p>
                <label for="email"></label>
                <p><input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="What's your email?" size="60"></p>
                <label for="phone"></label>
                <p><input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="What's your phone number?" size="60"></p>
                <label for="tags"> </label>
                <p><input id="tags" placeholder="What question do you have?"></p>
                <label for="info"></label>
                <p><textarea id="info" name="info" placeholder="More information..." rows="7 " cols="49"></textarea></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="submit">
        <button id="submit-button">Send Message</button>
    </div>
</div>


<footer>
    <p>&copy; Random Analytix. All rights reserved. </p>
    <a class="footer-link" href="https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/">CSS Validator</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="https://validator.w3.org">HTML Validator</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="services.html">Services</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="founder2.html">Founder</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="about-us.html">Our Story</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a>
</footer>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me, I edited the code snippet if you want to run it and open it in full-page view to see.

Comment: sorry i edited my answer, you just need the footer will be fixed and bottom 0

Comment: hey for some reason it still overlaps

Answer (score 0):

The footer in you picture isb't fully at the bottom, because you page doesn't fill the whole screen (vertical). You could change the size of the content of your page to fill the whole height minus the height of the footer using the `calc()` function, so the page fills the whole screen.

Or you could wrap your whole page into a container with the min-height 100vh and align your footer to the bottom (I'd prefer this way).

Hope I could help

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, I am new to coding so I have no idea what this means. BTW: I edited the code snippet if you want to run it and open it in full-page view to see.

Comment: I found a website which explains it a lot better than I can possibly do: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/ it shows 5 ways to archieve this exact thing

Comment: Hey thanks for the link, still didn't work out for some reason. :(

Comment: Have you tried every soloution? For me the 2nd looks very promising

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work :(

Comment: Have you tried different browsers? Maybe it's a browser issue?